# Horizontal slide effect between two divs with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs where I use a slide effect between them clicking a button, it looks like this:

```js
function openNav() {
  $(".lediv1").animate({
    left: '-100%'
  }, {
    duration: 500,
    start: function() {
      $(".lediv2").show().animate({
        left: '0%'
      }, 500);
    },
    complete: function() {
      $(".lediv1").css({
        "display": "none"
      });
    }
  });
}

function closeNav() {
  $(".lediv2").animate({
    left: '100%'
  }, {
    duration: 500,
    start: function() {
      $(".lediv1").animate({
        left: '0%'
      }, 500);
    },
    complete: function() {
      $(".lediv1").show();
      $(".lediv2").hide();
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="lediv1" style="position: relative; width: 100%; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px;background:#F00;float:left;">
    <div>
      <div class="text-center">Hello Hello!</div>
      <div class="text-center">Hello Hello!</div>
      <div class="text-center">Hello Hello!</div>
      <button class="closebtnT" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()"> go </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lediv2" style="display:none;position: relative; width: 100%; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px;background:#FF0;float:left;">
    <div>
      <div class="text-center">I don't know why you say goodbye, I say hello!</div>
      <div class="text-center">I don't know why you say goodbye, I say hello!</div>
      <div class="text-center">I don't know why you say goodbye, I say hello!</div>
      <div class="text-center">I don't know why you say goodbye, I say hello!</div>
      <div class="text-center">I don't know why you say goodbye, I say hello!</div>
      <div class="text-center">I don't know why you say goodbye, I say hello!</div>
      <div class="text-center">I don't know why you say goodbye, I say hello!</div>
      <button style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="closeNav()"> back </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is I want div's position looks like this, during the animation:

[image]

I added the **float:left** attribute in CSS but it's not working.

How can I fix it?

I'd like your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function openNav() {
    $("#slideWrapper").animate({left: '-100%'}, 500);
}

function closeNav() {
    $("#slideWrapper").animate({left: '0%'}, 500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;">
<div id="slideWrapper" style="width:200%;position:relative;white-space:nowrap">
  <div class="lediv1" style="width:50%;background:#F00;display:inline-block;">
    <div>
      <div class="text-center">Hello Hello!</div>
    <button  class="closebtnT" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()"> go </button>
    </div>       
  </div>
  <div class="lediv2" style="width:50%;background:#FF0;;display:inline-block;">
    <div>
      <div class="text-center">I don't know why you say goodbye, I say hello!</div>
      <button  style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="closeNav()"> back </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works great but, what happen if I have different amount of content in those divs? For example, I have a paragraph of 3 lines in one div and a paragraph of 6 lines in the other. I tried to change to `min-height:height:50px;` but it's not working.

Comment: Well that's incorrect syntax. Should be: `min-height:50px`.

Comment: But now that I think of it with absolute positioning that wouldn't work. Let me edit real quick.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake when I was writing, It's `min-height:50px`. I edited my question with that change.

Comment: edited the code to not use absolute positioning, so the height should be able to be auto now.

Comment: I had to remove that `display:inline-block` line to get a better appearance, thank you!